# string.Replace symbols

Tags: c#, xml, replace, fetchxml

i want to replace some symbols in fetchxml query

> Fetchxml.Replace("\"", "'").Replace("\n", "\"+").Replace("<", "\"<");

I want to replace \n (return to the line) with "+
and replace the < with "< 
But 
the Replace("\n", "\"+") that doesn't work it still \n 
and the Replace("<", "\"<") it replace the < with \"< istead of "<

Sample XML:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false"> <entity name="account"> <attribute name="name" /> <filter type="and"> <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" /> </filter> <link-entity name="contact" from="contactid" to="primarycontactid" visible="false" link-type="outer" alias="accountprimarycontactidcontactcontactid"> <attribute name="emailaddress1" /> </link-entity> </entity> </fetch>
```

Desired output:

```
<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>"+ "<entity name='account'>"+ "<filter type='and'>"+ "<condition attribute='statecode' operator='eq' value='0' />"+ "</filter>"+ "</entity>"+ "</fetch>
```

Comment: Please give some examples of what your XML looks like, especially before and after. "Replace" is probably not at good choice, because XML doesn't work like that.

Comment: Ok my fetchxml is like that Fetxml = "<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="account">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name="contact" from="contactid" to="primarycontactid" visible="false" link-type="outer" alias="accountprimarycontactidcontactcontactid">
      <attribute name="emailaddress1" />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>";

Comment: and After i want it to be Like that        and after i want it to be like that  : Fetchxml= "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>"+
  "<entity name='account'>"+
    "<filter type='and'>"+
      "<condition attribute='statecode' operator='eq' value='0' />"+
    "</filter>"+
  "</entity>"+
"</fetch>";

Comment: OK, what are you trying to accomplish with that output? Because that doesn't really look like XML any more? (I've edited your XML into the question - I haven't touched the formatting - you might want to check it, because it can be important).

Answer (score 0):

It looks what you're trying to do is simply insert '+' into the text elements of this XML. This is a bit of an odd thing to be doing, but I'll bite.

I would suggest this is easy in Perl, using `XML::Twig`. The problem with XML is it doesn't parse easily with regex, but it *does* parse easily with an XML parser.

So given input XML of:

```
<fetch distinct="false" mapping="logical" output-format="xml-platform" version="1.0">
  <entity name="account">
    <attribute name="name"/>
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0"/>
    </filter>
    <link-entity alias="accountprimarycontactidcontactcontactid" from="contactid" link-type="outer" name="contact" to="primarycontactid" visible="false">
      <attribute name="emailaddress1"/>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

It can be turned into a close approximation of your desired *output* XML:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings; 
my $xml = XML::Twig->new(
    'pretty_print'  => 'indented',
    'twig_handlers' => {
        'attribute'   => sub { $_->delete },
        'link-entity' => sub { $_->delete },
    },
);
$xml->parse( \*DATA );
$xml ->print;
```

This gives you:

```
<fetch distinct="false" mapping="logical" output-format="xml-platform" version="1.0">
  <entity name="account">
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0"/>
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

(If you don't want it line separated and indented, turn off that `pretty_print` flag)
Now, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish with the `+` symbols there. Are you perhaps trying to quote your XML result? In all honesty, that doesn't really make an awful lot of sense from an XML perspective.

If you *really* had to though, I guess you could:

```
my $output_xml = $xml ->sprint;
$output_xml =~ s/^\s+//gm;
$output_xml =~ s/\n</"+ "</g;
print $output_xml;
```

Which would give you:

```
<fetch distinct="false" mapping="logical" output-format="xml-platform" version="1.0">"+ "<entity name="account">"+ "<filter type="and">"+ "<condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0"/>"+ "</filter>"+ "</entity>"+ "</fetch>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but i want  to convert it with c# , because when i enter my fetchxml query , in the code the retourn to line it added so i must replace (\n) with "+

Comment: You get much better language specific answers, if you actually tag your question with a language.